# Populating a chart with contents of frame only if option box is selected?

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I have a user form with a "Select all that apply" series of boxes.

When the user selects OptionBox A, a frame appears with pass/fail radio buttons and six text boxes which store the upper and lower ends of three different ranges.

So: 
Option Box 1 is selected and then that runs: 
Pass/fail then Range 1 X% to X%
               Range 2 X% to X%
               Range 3 X% to X%

I only want to insert the answers from the three "All that Apply" Boxes that are toggled, have those pass/fail and range boxes to populate a table when the OptionBox is selected. When it is not selected, I would like nothing to appear, so no "Error! No Document Variable Supplied!" So, it would work if just OptionBox 1 is selected, it runs the code for 1, then if 1 and 3, only one and 3 skipping 2, etc.

I'm doing all of this with Doc Variables, I don't know if that's the right way to go. The code listed below works in that it populates the doc with the entries, but it displays with "Error! Document Variable not Supplied!" if I don't list anything and I'm not sure how to get it to not do that.

So this is part of the code:

```
Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()

If OptionButton11.Value = True Then oVars("RecoveryPass") = _ "Pass      language." Else oVars("RecoveryPass") = _ "Fail: Failure statement." ActiveDocument.Fields.Update Me.Repaint End If

If CheckBox2 = True Then Set oVars = ActiveDocument.Variables oVars("Mean1").Value = Me.Mean1.Value ActiveDocument.Fields.Update Me.Repaint

Set oVars = ActiveDocument.Variables
oVars("Mean2").Value = Me.mean2.Value
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
Me.Repaint


Set oVars = ActiveDocument.Variables
oVars("HW1").Value = Me.HW1.Value
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
Me.Repaint


Set oVars = ActiveDocument.Variables
oVars("HW2").Value = Me.HW2.Value
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
Me.Repaint

Set oVars = ActiveDocument.Variables
oVars("LS1").Value = Me.LS1.Value
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
Me.Repaint

Set oVars = ActiveDocument.Variables
oVars("LS2").Value = Me.LS2.Value
ActiveDocument.Fields.Update
Me.Repaint

End If

Me.Repaint UserForm3.hide

End Sub
```

---

I have very little idea of what I'm doing, this is my first time working on anything like this and it's making me want to jump out the window.

Comment: Your actual question isn't clear... Where and when is the error about document variables appearing, exactly? My best guess, based on the information, is that you have DocVariable fields in the document with no corresponding Document Variables. The Document Variables must be present, or the fields need to be removed. A Document Variables cannot be "empty", but you can assign a "space" character (which will reflect in the document). If that's a problem, you can format the field result as "hidden"...